# Android - dynamically load JAR file generated on Java

Tags: java, android, class, loading

I want to load Java classes dynamically on Android application.

I have the .jar file and I can create the .dex file on that jar with command dx. Then, how can I use them to load the classes i need in an Android application ?
I would to use them like:

```
DynamicLoadedClassJar obj = new DynamicLoadedClassInJar()
...
DynamicLoadedClassInJar obj = (DynamicLoadedClassInJar) ...
```

All I have is .jar file and I can generate .dex file (but I don't know how to use them).
Can you give me a snippet of code for this? Thank you

Comment: Note that what you are describing violates the Play Store developer distribution rules, which bans this sort of dynamic code loading (where the code does not come from the Play Store itself).

Comment: I know, I don't want to publish that. It's for personal use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can load jar and call a method on any of its classes

```
URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(jarPath.toURL(), this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Class classToLoad = Class.forName("yourPackage.yourClass", true, child);
Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod");
Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance();
Object result = method.invoke(instance);
```

Comment: It should work ideally. If your har consists of a dex file you may want to use DexClassLoader instead

Comment: How can I use this way to cast an object without knowing the name class, but an interface that is implemented by the class?

Es. in Jar I have `class A implements Int`, how can I do `Int a = (Int) obj` after that use of class loader?